# How can I identify the purpose of this unused cable?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I noticed an electrical box in my basement with a blank faceplate on it, and a single 12/2 cable running to it.

I tested the line for power, and was dead. So I removed the faceplate to investigate. Inside, the cable is coiled up, and the word “load” is written on the sheathing.

What is this?

I have exterior landscape lighting outlets that have no power. Could these issues be connected??

[image]

Comment: Unlikely they're related issues.  Not nearly enough information to diagnose.  You'll need to visually trace that wire to see where it goes and what (if anything) it's connected to.  It looks like it's never been connected to anything, so possibly put in for future use, but without more info, it's impossible to know for sure.

Comment: The fact that the individual wires are not capped off is a sure sign the other end of the cable isn't hooked to anything at the other end. (someone conscientious enough to label it would not create a fire-starting situation).  As far as the outdoor outlets, look for a tripped GFCI somewhere. Outdoor outlets are supposed to be GFCI protected, and so people often feed them from the Load terminals of a GFCI to use the downline protection feature. (of course they're supposed to get "GFCI Protected" labels when you do that!)

Comment: Does this line go to the exterior lighting that is not working? Perhaps there used to be a GFCI outlet here. I'm thinking maybe it was not wired properly and an inspector called it out, causing the former homeowner to remove it?

Comment: Find the origin of the landscape lighting wires, they should all start at a transformer or clock or computer, and that should be plugged into an outlet.  Can you add pictures of that and a description of what you see?   Note whether the outlet is a GFCI one (has a couple of buttons in it).  If there is a yellow cable just like this one going into the outlet that the clock is plugged into, I can propose a theory.

Comment: Is the theory, @jay613, that someone used NM-B cable inappropriately in an outdoor situation? ;)

Comment: @FreeMan theory (poor and unsubstantiated but since you asked) is there was a GFCI here feeding a downstream outlet for the lighting transformer via this cable.  Maybe the feeder wire was hijacked for something else?  Maybe the inspector didn't like something about it?  Maybe the transformer is not outside, or its outlet is on an outside wall hence the NM is ok?   IDK ....  we have two clues, I'm combining them. :)

Comment: All: thank you for the theories/suggestions. I’m at work, and can’t follow up thoroughly at the moment. I’ll do so this evening. Short answer, I believe this might be a load connection point for the landscape lighting outlets (which are located on an exterior wall and are transformed to low voltage). TBD.

Answer (score 2):

The marking of "load" on the wire suggests that this was intended to be a GFCI protecting some load, - possibly the outside lights, you'll have to follow the cable to know for sure, but in an exposed basement wiring situation that should be do-able. If it does go to outside lights it should transition to an outside-type cable or wires in conduit (rather than NM/B which is not wet-rated) before leaving the building.

The single cable, with the wire ends not even stripped suggests that it was never completed. Is there a sump with no pump nearby?

An alternate hypothesis is that this cable is a load connection from some GFCI to this location and a receptacle was never installed, and perhaps the other end was never connected.

Comment: Your alternate hypothesis might be correct. If that’s the case, does this location need a GFCI receptacle, or will a standard one do?

Comment: If it originates at the load terminals of another GFCI, or from a GFCI breaker, no. If it is not GFCI protected upstream it would need to be a GFCI here.

Answer (score -3):

It looks like an outlet to me, for a power point or a wired-in appliance.  It would be normal for the cable to be not connected at the switchboard.

To be safe, you should call an electrician who can use a tone generator.

If you want to do it yourself (dangerous to you and possibly the multi-meter) -

1. Ensure it is not live and does not read any voltage between line and neutral.
2. Confirm the outside is not live and there is no voltage either
3. Connect Line and Neutral together at one end
4. Measure the impedance to confirm if they are the same cable.

Comment: Huh? This makes no sense. OP has one end, doesn't know where the other end is. Your list here sounds like a way to check if one end matches the other end.